# How to add a rounded border on a drawable resource

Tags: android, drawable

I have an image inside mipmap folder and I am using it as a icon in toolbar . What I need to do is to add a rounded border around that drawable image .

Here is the code for my toolbar

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/account"
        android:icon="@mipmap/account_default"
        android:title="@string/tab_account"
        app:showAsAction="always" />
</menu>
```

However I have accomplished that , first I have converted that `drawable` into a a `Bitmap` then I added a rounded border around that bitmap and then again I converted that bitmap into `drawable`  .

I can accomplish that in another way , by using a custom toolbar and then use a circular `ImageView` . But due to some reason I can't do that for now .

Is there any other way I can accomplish that ?

Comment: can you add some code? In simple, you can use drawable shape

Comment: @AmolG I have added

Answer (score 0):

Its simple and easy way is you can use `CardView` with corner Radius

```
  <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:cardCornerRadius="15dp"
        android:layout_margin="15dp"
        android:elevation="10dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/round_image_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/image"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            />
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: This doesn't answer my question, as I have already mentioned this is for toolbar.